# ReactJS MaterialUI Modal not refreshing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

i have a Modal:

[image]

with certain fields, if i open the dropdown and select one of the fields, it does change the state of the Object but doesnt render it in the UI (i reopen the dropdown with the selections so you can see whats behind):

[image]

the weird thing about it is, if i do it outside of the Modal, it does work, so it has anything todo with my Modal component?

Here is the BaseModal component:

```html
declare interface IBaseModal {
    readonly sx: BaseModalStyle;
    readonly body?: React.ReactNode;
    readonly isOpen: boolean;
    readonly toggleModal: any;
}

const BaseModal: FC<IBaseModal> = ({sx, body, isOpen, toggleModal}: IBaseModal) => (
    <Modal open={isOpen} onClose={toggleModal}>
        <BaseModalView width={sx.width} height={sx.height}>
            {body}
        </BaseModalView>
    </Modal>
)
```

then i use it as follows in the view component:

```html
<BaseModal
                sx={{width: 800, height: 600}}
                isOpen={isModalOpen}
                toggleModal={() => setModalOpen(isModalOpen)}
                body={modalBody}
            />
```

```html
    const localizer = momentLocalizer(moment);
    const [events, setEvents] = useState<CalendarEvent[]>([])
    const [schedule, setSchedule] = useState<ISchedule>(initialScheduleEvent);
    const [isModalOpen, setModalOpen] = useState<boolean>(false);
    const [modalBody, setModalBody] = useState<React.ReactNode | undefined>();

    const handleSelectDate = (e: SlotInfo) => {
        setModalBody(<Grid container>
            <Grid item xs={6}>
                <Grid container direction="row" sx={{padding: 2}}>
                    <Grid item xs={12} sx={{marginBottom: 2}}>
                        <Typography variant="h5" align='center'>
                            Schedule your Post
                        </Typography>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item xs={12} sx={{marginBottom: 2}}>
                        <Divider/>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item xs={12} paddingBottom={3}>
                        <TextField
                            style={{marginBottom: 20}}
                            fullWidth
                            select
                            variant="outlined"
                            label="Plattform"
                            value={schedule.platform}
                            onChange={e => setSchedule(prevState => ({...prevState, platform: e.target.value}))}
                        >
                            {availableSocialMedias.map(item => (
                                <MenuItem key={item.socialMedia} value={item.socialMedia}>{item.socialMedia}</MenuItem>
                            ))}
                        </TextField>

                        <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
                            <DateTimePicker
                                renderInput={(props) => <TextField {...props} />}
                                label="Schedule Date and Time"
                                value={schedule.schedule.start}
                                onChange={(e) => {
                                    setSchedule(prevState =>  ({...prevState, schedule: {
                                            ...prevState.schedule, start: e!
                                        }}))
                                }}
                            />
                        </LocalizationProvider>
                        <TextField
                            fullWidth
                            margin="dense"
                            multiline
                            rows="5"
                            variant="outlined"
                            label="Post Content"
                            id="additional-info"
                            value={schedule.schedule.desc}
                            onChange={(e) => {
                                setSchedule(prevState =>  ({...prevState, schedule: {
                                        ...prevState.schedule, desc: e.target.value
                                    }}))
                            }}
                        />
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item xs={12} sx={{width: '100%'}}>
                        <Stack spacing={2} direction="row" justifyContent='center'>
                            <Button variant='contained' onClick={() => createEvent()}>Post</Button>
                            <Button variant='contained' onClick={() => handleCloseModal()}>Close</Button>
                        </Stack>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={6} sx={{backgroundColor: '#F7706EFF', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
                <img style={{height: 250, width: 400}}
                     src={"https://web-static.wrike.com/blog/content/uploads/2020/01/Five-Features-of-a-Good-Monthly-Employee-Work-Schedule-Template.jpg?av=718acbc1e2b21264368f12b5cc57c0e2"}/>
                <img style={{height: 250, width: 400}}
                     src={"https://imageio.forbes.com/specials-images/imageserve/605e039657de8844e59d9140/Businesswoman-Planning-Schedule-Using-Calendar-And-Laptop/0x0.jpg?format=jpg&crop=922,615,x0,y0,safe&width=960"}/>
                <Typography align='center' variant='h6'>
                    Schedule for the whole week!
                </Typography>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>)

        setModalOpen(true);
    }
```

It also rerenders after i select a certain value in the dropdown for example. but the Modal does not update its value, and i dont get why... i hope for any help.

**Small Edit:**
After selecting a value and closing / reopening the Modal, the value does change, but why not straight after selecting it but after reopening it?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue having the Body of the Modal, not in a variable but straight in the return body of the component